# Transient solution of current in circuit with two coupled inductors, with resistances

Tags: current, waveform, pspice, transient, circuit-theory

Circuit in question is given below. I want to find why I can not get the
same current waveform as PSpice gives me.

[image]

Basically I want to calculate formula for i1(t) by hand and get something as close as possible to what PSpice gives me. Either my math is wrong or PSpice is using some model that I am not familiar with.

Assume: No accumulated energy in the inductors and perfect coupling between inductors.
(Note: My PSpice works well for k=1, if someone tries to simulate below circuit and gets error(s) because of k=1,then just put 0.99 for coupling coefficient)
Switch closes at t=1us,and TTRAN=0.1us.

My transient calculation for i1(t) gives me

$$i1(t)=\frac{E}{R1}*(1-e^{-\frac{R1*R2}{L1*R2+L2*R1}*t})$$

What I did is, I used KVL for two loops, with coupled inductors in them. Then I solved the system of two ODEs and found the i1(t). This is the system I use to find i1(t):
$$E-i1*R1-L1*\frac{di1}{dt}-M*\frac{di2}{dt}=0$$
$$i2*R2+L2*\frac{di2}{dt}+M*\frac{di1}{dt}=0$$
$$M=-1*\sqrt{L1*L2}\text{ (see dots and currents assumed in the picture above)}$$

Simulations done in PSpice for various L1 values, do not agree with what I get when I use my derived expression for i1(t). Simulated curves for i1(t) are not so exponential in nature, as my formula above suggests. For i.e. when L1 is small, like in uH, i1 peaks very fast, according to PSPice.
That actually happens when ratio L2/L1 is big.
See image(s) below.

From looking at the wave forms I would say that i1(t) function is composed of linear part(with steep slope) which then continues as exponential curve.

So,

1. Is my math wrong or I am using circuit model which is limited in same way so that I can not get
   the same result as PSpice.
   As far as I know K_linear works like linear transformer without core losses.
   I did try to use this model:
   https://resources.pcb.cadence.com/blog/2019-creating-a-linear-transformer-model-for-circuit-simulations.It is T-mesh plus ideal transformer and my math gives me the same result again.
2. If my math is OK, then why I am not getting what PSpice gives me? My suspect is that there is
   something with K_linear part and the way it works.
3. What i1(t) is/should be? Looks like it is not just exponential function.
4. For i1(t) and i2(t), what would be the inital conditions?
   For i1, I use the fact that current is zero,at t=0 (iL1(0)=0).
   For finding i2(t), I would use voltage accross L1 at t=0 to be equal to E (uL1(0)=E). Is this right?

Images of i1(t) current I get for different L1 values in PSpice are below.
(Sorry for not overlaying those curves.It was easier for me to do them separately.)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The primary side inductor at \$t=0s\$ will behave just like an open circuit but "transformer action" will occur at \$t=0s\$ as well. So we cannot ignore it.

Thus for \$L_1 = 50mH\$ and \$L_2 = 100mH\$ the turn ratio is:

$$N= \sqrt{\frac{L_1}{L_2}}= \sqrt{\frac{50mH}{100mH}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \approx 0.707$$

thus the resistance \$R_2\$ is seen at the primary side ( reflected resistance) as a resistor equal to:

$$R_r = N^2*R_2 = 0.5k\Omega$$

Therefore the voltage across the primary inductance at \$t=0s\$ is

$$V_{L1(0s)} = 12V \frac{0.5k\Omega}{1k\Omega +0.5k\Omega} = 4V$$

And the current is

$$I_{L1(0s)} = \frac{12V - 4V}{1k\Omega} = 8mA$$

And the current will start to rise exponential from \$8mA\$ to \$12mA\$ with a time constant equal to:

$$\tau = \frac{L_1}{R_1||(N^2R_2)}$$

And all of this is true for \$K = 1\$ at least I hope so.

Comment: This looks ok. I will look it in depth tomorrow. 
In time constant , why you use R1 in parallel with N^2*R2 ,and not series connection R1+N^2*R2 ?  As far as I know you just lose loop with L2 and instead of L1 you put N^2*R2. Thanks for reply.

Comment: You are right,my bad. It is R1||(N^2*R2) !This will give the same time constant as I get in my calculations. It is just not self evident when you draw the equivalent circuit with reflected R2,R1 and E.That's why I thought it is R1+N^2*R2 ,and not R1 || N^2*R2.

Comment: The reflected resistance manifest itself in parallel with L1 thus the resistance seen by a L1 is R1||Rr (we short all the voltage source)

Answer (score 0):

1. My math is almost ok.See (4)
2. K_Liner works as it should, in the way described in the link provided above and in Help documentation of PSpice.
3. Problem is with initial condition. For I1 is not just i1(0)=0, but what @G36 showed. I've completely disregarded 'transformer action'
4. We don't know initial conditions *per se* but we can find C1 and C2 (and then i1(t) and i2(t), for k=1) like this:

$$
i_1(t)=C1*e^{-\frac{(R1*R2)t}{R1*L2+R2*L1}}+\frac{E}{R1}
\\
i_2(t)=C2*e^{-\frac{(R1*R2)t}{R1*L2+R2*L1}}
\\~\\
u_{l1}(t)=E-i_1(t)*R1;\: u_l1(0)=E-R1*C1-E=-R1*C1
\\
u_{l2}(t)=i_2(t)*R2;\: u_{l2}(0)=C2*R2
\\~\\
\frac{u_{l1}}{u_{l2}}=\frac{N1}{N2}=\frac{\sqrt{L1}}{\sqrt{L2}};\:\: \frac{i_l1}{i_{l2}}=\frac{N1}{N2}=\frac{\sqrt{L2}}{\sqrt{L1}}\text{, system to be solved for t=0}
\\~\\
\frac{-R1*C1}{R2*C2}=\frac{\sqrt{L1}}{\sqrt{L2}}
\\
\frac{C1+\frac{E}{R1}}{C2}=\frac{\sqrt{L2}}{\sqrt{L1}}
\\~\\
\text{Solution:}
\\~\\
C2=E*\frac{\sqrt{L1*L2}}{L1*R2+R1*L2}
\\
C1=-E*\frac{R2}{R1}*\frac{L1}{L1*R2+R1*L2}
$$
Now, we have both i1(t) and i2(t).

Comment: The unit of C2 is Amper ---> Current = Voltage x Siemens but for C1 what is the unit? For me, C1 should look like this: $$ \large C_1 = - E \times \frac{L_1 \frac{R_2}{R_1}}{L_1R_2+L_2R_1}$$  Because now the units are satisfied. So remember always check the units.

Comment: I've made a writing mistake. Sorry.Original answer is corrected now,